# How can I pass a Fragment to a context parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this function and I'd like to call it within a fragment.

```
fun showProgressBar(context: Context) : ProgressDialog {
        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog((context))
        progressDialog.isIndeterminate = true
        progressDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.progress_loading))
        progressDialog.show()
        return progressDialog
    }
```

That's how I call in an activity: `val mProgressDialog = Utils.showProgressBar(this@MainActivity)`
Calling it in a fragment `val mProgressDialog = Utils.showProgressBar(this@HomeFragment)` throws this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Fragment has methods [`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) and [`getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getContext()) (or just `activity` and `context` in Kotlin). To get a context from a Fragment, you just need to do

```kotlin
Utils.showProgressBar(activity)
// or
Utils.showProgressBar(context)
```

Note that `activity` or `context` can be null depending on when in the lifecycle you call it. To require a non-null context/activity you can use

```kotlin
val ctx = requireContext()
// or
val act = requireActivity()
```

which will either return a non-null activity (context) or throw and `IllegalStateException`

Answer (score 2):

[The `Fragment` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html) has many methods. One of these [is `requireContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#requireContext()), which will attempt to give you a `Context` to use. This will only work while the fragment is attached to an activity.